# How to find the instance of a control in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I have the following XAML where myList is a user control. On that user control I have a textblock and a delete button. When a user presses the delete button, I want to delete the instance of that selected user control. How do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use visibility.collapsed instead of deleting control from objects tree?